# Message Passing System

Tags: operating-system

I was reading "Message-Passing Systems" section from "Operating System Concepts" by Galvin and I came across this:

> Messages sent by a process can be of either fixed or variable size. If only fixed-sized 
>    messages can be sent, the system-level implementation is straightforward. This restriction, 
>    however,makes the task of programming very difficult.

I am unable to understand why programming task is difficult and system-level implementation easy in this case. Can someone please elaborate this statement.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all messages are the same size you can allocate a pool of fixed-size buffers for messages from appropriate memory so the OS side is easy.

This makes the application side more difficult because all messages have to fit in the same size block of memory.  You can't pass a string without having code to decide what to do if it is too long, for example.